# Split a column with lists and then join them back and differentiate between original and duplicate

Tags: python, list, split, nested, left-join

I would like to split a column with lists and then join them back and differentiate between original and duplicate:

Input Table

```
| Id | Text
| -------- | -------------- |
| 1a2b3c| [apple, banana, snake, sorry, keyboard, light]|
| 4a5b6c| [program, information, belly, juice]
| 7a8b9c| [monkey, sand, forum]|
```

Output Table

```
| Id| Text | Duplicate or Original |
|:---- |:------:| -----:|
| 1a2b3  | [apple, banana]| Original
| 1a2b3  | [snake, sorry]| Duplicate
| 1a2b3  | [keyboard, light]| Duplicate
| 4a5b6c  | [program, information]| Original
| 4a5b6c  | [ belly, juice]| Duplicate
| 7a8b9c  | [monkey, sand]| Original
| 7a8b9c| [forum]| Duplicate
```

I can't get my head around how to get this output on Python.
Any suggestions or examples?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What discriminates between `Original` or `Duplicate` label?

Comment: The rows after "Original" will be Duplicates beside the content in the list.

Comment: I think that a more complete example would be useful for us to understand how to best help you